# Unable to install Hyper-V-Hypervisor

Tags: windows, installation, virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor

**Update: I can't check any suggestions anymore as I dosn't have this installation anymore**

I'm trying to install Hyper-V on my PC.
But I have a problem.
Every time I tried to install it I have the problem that on reboot Windows perfoms an update (looks like the normal Windows Update) but is unable to complete it and then it removes the changes.
I followed [this](https://windowsreport.com/cant-install-hyper-v-windows-10/) guide step by step (except the fresh start) and ended on installing the components individually.
So my result:
I installed the services, the GUI and the PowerShell module. But when I install the Hypervisor it always happens the same (like I described above).
I already removed VMWare and never had anything else.
But in the past I alreaday had Hyper V once and it worked then.

Any idea why this doesn't work this time?
Thank you!

I have Windows 10 Pro x64.
And virtualization is enabled (and worked in the past).

Edit 1:
Here is the winver result:
[image: winver result]

Comment: Run the command `winver` in a Command Prompt (cmd) and post the result.

Comment: Can you try upgrading Windows to its **[final version](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4556826)**? Did you run **[Restoro](https://www.trustpilot.com/review/restoro.com)** on your computer?

Comment: thanks that you try to help me here too but I don't use this installation anymore and use Virtual Box now (and plan to have a seperate Proxmox host). This means that I can't try any solutions anymore, btw my current installation is already up-to-date :)